# spinner is not getting empty android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to make spinner empty to reload new data.

I have code like this to add data in spinner, which is working fine.

```
final Spinner mLocationProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_province_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyData>(
                                   getApplicationContext(),
                                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                   items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mLocationProvince.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, the problem is, every time, before load I want to make spinner empty.

**I tried with:**

```
mLocationProvince.setAdapter(null);
```

AND

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But, still it's appending the data in current list.

Comment: are you using a button to make the spinner empty, where are you calling the method to clear the spinner?, post your code.

Comment: @Jorgesys It's a function within activity class. and this function is being called after asyncTask completion (within `onPostExecute` method)

Answer (score 0):

declare `adapter` as a class variable:

```
private ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter;
```

your code will change to:

```
final Spinner mLocationProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_province_spinner);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyData>(
                                   getApplicationContext(),
                                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                   items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mLocationProvince.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and you can execute the method: `notifyDataSetChanged()` of the same adapter instance.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Tried it as well. Same result!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I tried to set the adapter to `null` and it worked, so i don't know why in your case it doesn't. By the way i tried also another possibility. When you want to make the spinner empty you can do:

```
 items.clear();
 mLocationProvince.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In this case you are clearing the `List` from which you take the dropdown list's informations of the `Spinner`. Then you can populate it again as you do normally and it will automatically refresh with new informations.

P.s. i did the example assuming that `items` is a List or an ArrayList. If it is an array you can simply re-assign it with `items = new String[0]`

Comment: Yes. But, now it's not loading even first list.

Comment: I can't know what you have to do with empty spinner and filled one. Share your rest of code and i can help more. With my code you can empty a spinner when you want and with yours you can fill it.